# Path changes but is not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React router isn't rendering my component. I'm not getting any errors and the URL is changing to the correct path.

```
//App component
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import AppNavbar from "./components/layout/Nav";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Category from "./components/create/Category";
import Item from "./components/create/Item";
import StockCategory from "./components/category/StockCategory";
import SignIn from "./components/auth/SignIn";
import Book from "./components/book/Book";

export class App extends Component {
state = {
stockItems: [
  {
    category: "events",
    name: "Keg",
    booked: true,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    category: "events",
    name: "tent",
    booked: false,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    category: "events",
    name: "speakers",
    booked: true,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    category: "production",
    name: "camera",
    booked: true,
    id: 4
  },
  {
    category: "production",
    name: "drone",
    booked: false,
    id: 5
  },
  {
    category: "production",
    name: "video camera",
    booked: true,
    id: 6
  }
],

categories: ["Events", "Production"]
};

render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <AppNavbar />
      <br />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/new/category" component={Category} />
        <Route path="/new/item" component={Item} />
        {this.state.categories.map(item => {
          return (
            <Route
              id={item}
              path="/category/:id"
              component={StockCategory}
            />
          );
        })}
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route exact path="/book" component={Book} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
}
}

export default App;

//Book component
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from "reactstrap";

export class Book extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col">
        <h2>Item Name</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Form>
      <FormGroup>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="Use"
          id="Use"
          placeholder="What are you using this for?"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Input
          type="number"
          name="Quantity"
          id="qty"
          placeholder="Quantity"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Input
          type="date"
          name="Return Date"
          id="returnDate"
          placeholder="Return Date"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <br />
      <br />

      <Button>Book</Button>
    </Form>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Book;

//stockCategory component
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import All from "./All";
import Available from "./Available";
import Booked from "./Booked";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Book from "../book/Book";

export class StockCategory extends Component {
state = {
stockItems: [
  {
    category: "events",
    name: "Keg",
    booked: true,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    category: "events",
    name: "tent",
    booked: false,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    category: "events",
    name: "speakers",
    booked: true,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    category: "production",
    name: "camera",
    booked: true,
    id: 4
  },
  {
    category: "production",
    name: "drone",
    booked: false,
    id: 5
  },
  {
    category: "production",
    name: "video camera",
    booked: true,
    id: 6
  }
],

categories: ["Events", "Production"]
};

componentDidMount() {
console.log(this.props.match);
}

render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="container text-center">
      <h1 className="text-center">
        {this.props.match.params.id.toUpperCase()}
      </h1>
      <br />
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col text-center">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item">
              <Link
                class="page-link"
                to={`/category/${this.props.match.params.id}`}
              >
                All
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
              <Link
                class="page-link"
                to={`/category/${this.props.match.params.id}/available`}
              >
                Available
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
              <Link
                class="page-link"
                to={`/category/${this.props.match.params.id}/booked`}
              >
                Booked
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          id={this.props.match.params.id}
          exact
          path={`/category/:id`}
          component={All}
        />
        <Route
          id={this.props.match.params.id}
          exact
          path={`/category/:id/available`}
          component={Available}
        />
        <Route
          id={this.props.match.params.id}
          exact
          path={`/category/:id/booked`}
          component={Booked}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
 );
}
}

export default StockCategory;

//child of stockCategory
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, Button, CardTitle, CardText } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export class All extends Component {
 state = {
 stockItems: [
  {
    category: "Events",
    name: "Keg",
    booked: true,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    category: "Events",
    name: "tent",
    booked: false,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    category: "Events",
    name: "speakers",
    booked: true,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    category: "Production",
    name: "camera",
    booked: true,
    id: 4
  },
  {
    category: "Production",
    name: "drone",
    booked: false,
    id: 5
  },
  {
    category: "Production",
    name: "video camera",
    booked: true,
    id: 6
  }
],

categories: ["Events", "Production"]
};

componentDidMount() {
console.log(this.props.match);
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="container">
    {this.state.stockItems.map(item => {
      if (
        item.booked === true &&
        item.category === this.props.match.params.id
      ) {
        return (
          <ul className="list-group">
            <li className="list-group-item">
              {item.name} <Button color="success">Return</Button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        );
      } else if (
        item.booked !== true &&
        item.category === this.props.match.params.id
      ) {
        return (
          <ul className="list-group">
            <li className="list-group-item">
              {item.name}{" "}
              <Link to="/book">
                <Button color="danger">Book</Button>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        );
      } else return null;
    })}
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default All;
```

I've read that the order of your routes matters, but that didn't seem to help either. Not really sure what the problem could be. Any help would be much appreciated!

To add more detail, when I click on `<Link/>` it takes me to the right URL but doesn't show the component. But if I reload the page then the component shows?

Comment: where do you specifiy the book router?

Comment: I can not see any route for <Link to="/book">, instead use <Link to="/category/book">

Comment: possibly you are missing `withRouter` while `export` of component

Comment: @ravibagul91 Sorry that was an old version. The current route is /book not /category/book and still doesn't work

Comment: post your all codes for each file

Comment: @Peyman There you go

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the link to codepen or some other online editor (try to provide a working code, which we can use to debug.). This way we can easily help debug also because going though many components and then debugging without the context of the component will be difficult.

Comment: @J.Hansen Sorry, i wan't online. Did you fix the problem?

Comment: @Peyman Sorry for the late response, was away for the weekend. But unfortunately I still haven't found a solution. Because clicking <Link/> still changes the URL but won't display the component until I refresh, I'm thinking of using a work around that checks the current URL and if it matches then the page will auto refresh.

Comment: @J.Hansen Okay, let me to recreate your application to examine the problem(s).

Comment: @Peyman I'll try recreate it and send you a link shortly. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Peyman So I managed to find the problem. I was using <BrowserRouter/> in two different components. All these days of stress for something so obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can only use browserRouter once in your component tree. As soon as I removed browserRouter from the second component everything worked fine.